Как избежать ошибки краша при send в сокетах?
Если использовать send в сокетах когда сокет закрывается, то программа не вернёт -1 а просто крашнется, я использую send(socket, buf, size, 0), система тестирования linux

select можно использовать

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); и запись во все закрытые дескрипторы будет возвращать -1 (errno  для stream сокетов установится в EPIPE)
